# Change boxplot color for boxplot displayed by categories

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my code and I have tried most functions to change the color and shape of my boxes but nothing seems to work .
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more complicated to use pandas + matplotlib, you have to set the face colors of the boxes:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':np.random.uniform(0,1,20),
'family_history':np.repeat(["No","Yes"],10)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
bplot = df.boxplot(column="Age",by="family_history",vert=False,
                   patch_artist=True,return_type='both',ax=ax)
colors = ['lightblue', 'lightgreen']
for patch, color in zip(bplot[0][1]['boxes'], colors):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)
```

[image]

Or you can use seaborn:

```
sns.boxplot(data = df,x = "Age",y="family_history",hue="family_history")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the palette option:

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')
sns.boxplot(x=df["clarity"], y=df["price"], palette="Reds", showfliers = False)
plt.show()
```